# Adding my items to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, blackjack

I have created 52 cards to be added to my ArrayList the only problem is when I try to get the first item in the list I can an outofboundserror because I don't think anything has been added to my ArrayList.

```
private ArrayList<Card> deck;

public Deck() {
    deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    for(int i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
        if(i == 1){
            Card c = new Card("Ace", "Hearts");
        }
        else if(i < 11 && i > 1) {
            Card c = new Card("" + i, "Hearts");
        }
        else if(i == 11) {
            Card c = new Card("Jack", "Hearts");
        }
        else if(i == 11) {
            Card c = new Card("Queen", "Hearts");
        }
        else if(i == 11) {
            Card c = new Card("King", "Hearts");
        }
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
        if(i == 1) {
            Card c = new Card("Ace", "Clubs");
        }
        else if(i < 11 && i > 1) {
            Card c = new Card("" + i, "Hearts");
        }
        else if(i == 11) {
            Card c = new Card("Jack", "Clubs");
        }
        else if(i == 11) {
            Card c = new Card("Queen", "Clubs");
        }
        else if(i == 11) {
            Card c = new Card("King", "Clubs");
        }
    }

    for(int i = 14; i < 1; i--) {
        if(i == 11) {
            Card c = new Card("King", "Diamonds");
        }
        else if(i == 11) {
            Card c = new Card("Queen", "Diamonds");
        }
        else if(i == 11) {
            Card c = new Card("Jack", "Diamonds");
        }
        else if(i < 11 && i > 1) {
            Card c = new Card("" + i, "Diamonds");
        }
        else if(i == 1) {
            Card c = new Card("Ace", "Diamonds");
        }
    }

    for(int i = 14; i < 1; i--) {
        if(i == 11) {
            Card c = new Card("King", "Spades");
        }
        else if(i == 11) {
            Card c = new Card("Queen", "Spades");
        }
        else if(i == 11) {
            Card c = new Card("Jack", "Spades");
        }
        else if(i < 11 && i > 1) {
            Card c = new Card("" + i, "Spades");
        }
        else if(i == 1) {
            Card c = new Card("Ace", "Spades");
        }
    }
}
```

How would I go about adding this to my ArrayList?

Comment: `else if(i == 11)` is repeated 3 times. You really should pay attention to the code you are providing.

Comment: And, you have never actually _added_ a `Card` to the `deck`.

Answer (score 2):

To add cards to your deck you need to call

```
deck.add(c);
```

BTW it is pointless using a loop and checking for just one value in the loop.  You can just call that line of code once.

```
List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
for (String suit : "Hearts,Clubs,Diamonds,Spades".split(",")) {
   deck.add(new Card("Ace", suit));
   for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++)
       deck.add(new Card("" + i, suit));
   deck.add(new Card("Jack", suit));
   deck.add(new Card("Queen", suit));
   deck.add(new Card("King", suit));
}
```

Comment: I have tried calling it in the tester and the constructor but have had no luck

Comment: @Ian could you be more specific? I have added an example of how to shorten the code.